# is it possible to write to HBase and multiple files from the same reducer in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, multipleoutputs

we need to be able to write output of the map/reduce to multiple files (already working) as well as HBase table. Is this possible? I had been looking at the MultipleOutputs option, but I can't figure out how to do it or if it's even doable. I am very very new to haddop.
If somebody knows of any examples on the web, could you point me to the right direction please?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't tried this, but the API for [MultipleOutputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/MultipleOutputs.html) does support it. Because you configure the Output Key/Value classes independently for each named output, you can have one (or multiple) `*FileOutputFormat` and one for `TableOutputFormat`.